# I need a licens for an opensource project, that specifies not free for comertial use

Tags: licensing

I am developing a web based opensource project. I was considering the AGPL v3, but I explicitly want to prevent commercial use. Non-profit orgs are welcome to use it for free.

It seems to be a common thing in the software world, but I am looking for a pre-written license that I could use or adapt.

Any ideas where I can find such a thing? Are there accepted opensource licenses that fit this criteria?

Comment: belongs on programmers.stockexchange

Comment: Thanx, I didn't even know about it: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use such a license, because it is sometimes very hard to draw the line between commercial and non-commercial, especially juridically.

However, you may check out [Creative Commons licenses](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/).

Comment: http://wiki.creativecommons.org/FAQ#Can_I_use_a_Creative_Commons_license_for_software.3F
"**Can I use a Creative Commons license for software?**"
"We do not recommend it. Creative Commons licenses should not be used for software. We strongly encourage you to use one of the very good software licenses which are already available. We recommend considering licenses made available by the Free Software Foundation or listed at the Open Source Initiative. Unlike our licenses, which do not make mention of source or object code, these existing licenses were designed specifically for use with software."

Comment: I read somewhere that it wasn't a good idea to use these for software, but the Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 looks like an option. http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/3.0/

Comment: Well, then. There you have it. :) So it would seem I'm stuck with writing my own... I know, I know, also not recommended.

Comment: Writing your own is the worst idea.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any *open source* licenses that prevent commercial use. That's against the spirit of open source and wouldn't fit into the definition of open source.

Comment: As defined by who? :) My source is open, and free, but if you want to make money off it you can pay me for another kind of license.

Comment: @Jacques Bosch: As defined by the Open Source Definition.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Point taken. I'll have to call my project another kind of "...-source" then.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot possibly be such a license. Forbidding the use of the source code is the *exact opposite* of open source. Ergo, there cannot ever possible be an open source license which has such a restriction, and a license which has such a restriction cannot ever possibly be an open source license.